# Pandas Fill Not Null data with First Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

let say a dataset will have value as per below :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA1': ['OK', np.nan,'1', np.nan], 
                   'DATA2' : ['KO','2', np.nan, np.nan]})
df
```

Data will show as per below:

[image]

My objective is to replace all of row that have value (not null) to the first row value as per sample below :

[image]

I know that I can change the data directly, but I want to find a better solution if I have thousands of columns and row.

Thank You
Best Regards
Railey Shahril

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
final=pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.notnull(),df.iloc[0],df),df.index,df.columns)
```

---

```
  DATA1 DATA2
0    OK    KO
1   NaN    KO
2    OK   NaN
3   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first row:

```
df = df.mask(df.notna(), df.iloc[0], axis=1)
print (df)
  DATA1 DATA2
0    OK    KO
1   NaN    KO
2    OK   NaN
3   NaN   NaN
```

For replace by first non missing value use add `backfill`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA1': [ np.nan, 'OK','1', np.nan], 
                   'DATA2' : ['KO','2', np.nan, np.nan]})

print (df)
  DATA1 DATA2
0   NaN    KO
1    OK     2
2     1   NaN
3   NaN   NaN

df = df.mask(df.notna(), df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[0], axis=1)
print (df)
  DATA1 DATA2
0   NaN    KO
1    KO    KO
2    KO   NaN
3   NaN   NaN
```